# Added a custom framework, now Swift can't unarchive data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nskeyedunarchiver

I have a pretty trivial Swift app that has a model class named `DemoNote`. An array of `DemoNote` instances is read/written via keyed archiving. This worked fine while `DemoNote` was included in the app.

But then I moved `DemoNote.swift` to a new custom framework called `DemoSharedCode`. Aside from making sure Xcode was using the framework in the app target, I made sure to

- Mark `DemoNote` and its vars and methods as `public` so they'd be visible outside of the framework
- Add `import DemoSharedCode` to any classes that want to use `DemoNote`

So now the **compiler** is happy. But at run time the unarchiving fails with this error:

```
2015-02-17 12:12:53.417 DemoNotesSwift[70800:16504104] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason:
'*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class
(DemoNotesSwift.DemoNote)'
```

In the above, `DemoNotesSwift` is the app name, `DemoNote` is the class name, and the line of code is attempting to unarchive objects from an `NSData` blob:

```
let savedObjects = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(savedData) as? [(DemoNote)]
```

I'm guessing that moving `DemoNote` to the framework means its module name has changed, which breaks unarchiving, but I'm not sure of that. I'm also not sure what to do about it-- maybe I need to call `+setClass:forClassName:` on the unarchiver, but if so I don't know what the arguments would be.

Comment: What the archiver does internally is a bit misty. There's an open source project which can help reading archives (I gave up, too much of a nightmare). But it will likely store some class signature. So if you change that under the hood (which is never a good idea) it will (as likely in your case) croak. Just an idea, not based on practical experience.

Comment: I previously did the same thing in Objective-C (literally, as in I'm doing the same demo project in a different language) and it was OK. It's got to be possible to do the same thing in Swift.

Comment: I see. So I guess the Swift framework now differs. Though there's some toll-free bridging between both languages it does not seem to work here. You're probably left to try and error :-/ I guess you already googled for `NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException` and found the SO answers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Moving `DemoNote` from the app to a framework did change the module name, which meant that `NSKeyedUnarchiver` couldn't find instances of the archived class due to a name mismatch. The fix was to add this line before unarchiving:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(DemoNote.self, forClassName: "DemoNotesSwift.DemoNote")
```

In this case, `DemoNote.self` gets the current full class name, and `DemoNotesSwift.DemoNote` is what the class used to be called when it was part of the app.

This was only necessary because I had previously existing data that I wanted to keep.

Comment: Where can I find a tutorial on creating a 100% Swift framework?  -- I'm a framework neophyte and have just mastered an ObjC framework for Swift.  But I don't know how to collect 'headers'/ObjC within Swift which doesn't have headers.

Comment: do you happen to know also how to make nskeyedarchiver to archive the class with the correct name the next time it stores it?

Comment: Normally it isn't a problem, I only had a problem because of my refactoring. If you really need it, `NSKeyedArchiver` has a method that's the reverse of the one I used-- `setClassName(_: forClass:)`

Comment: Although I don't know the details, you can use also `NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(DemoNote.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "DemoNotesSwift.DemoNote")`, the method `classForKeyedUnarchiver()` looks more suitable.

Comment: It looks like that method is intended if you want to override the default class-- that is, specifically if you **don't** want to use `ClassName.self` but want some other class instead. It's useful in some situations but I think it's less appropriate in this case.

Comment: This answer won't work for nested objects, check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46832840/1433612