# Cannot decode object of class Employee for key (NS.object.0); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

Im trying to pass an array of 'Employee' objects iPhone to Apple Watch by serializing the array :

```
NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:employees];
```

and unserializing it as on the Watch side:

```
NSMutableArray *employees = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
```

This is the 'Employee' class:

```
@interface Employee : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * employeeID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * age;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * designation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * teamName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * gender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * dateOfJoining;
@end
```

Do I have to do any changes on the Watch side to fix this error?

Comment: It looks like the code doing the decoding doesn't know about the `Employee` class.  Is it being compiled into the watch side?

Comment: Yes. I have to show list of Employees on the watch

Comment: make sure that Employee class added in the Watch target and it conforms NSCoding protocol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I encode a subclass of NSManagedObject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371749/can-i-encode-a-subclass-of-nsmanagedobject)

Comment: Do you realize that a managed object can't be passed to another thread, managed object context, or device?

Answer (score 40):

so I just had that exact same problem and the answer is simple but a little hard to find by oneself.

You simply have to use:

- `NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("Employee", for: Employee.self)`
  before serializing
- `NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Employee.self, forClassName: "Employee")`
  before deserializing

wherever needed.

Looks like iOS extensions prefix the class name with the extension's name.

Comment: Thank You. The fun of upgrading large app from objc to swift.

Answer (score 12):

For me it was happening in my Today extension. What fixed it was adding **@objc(MyExampleClass)** before the declaration.

```
@objc(MyExampleClass)
open class MyExampleClass {
....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

teriiehina's answer got me part of the way there; I could archive and unarchive to clean devices but still got the above error when trying to unarchive an existing archive.

Eventually I found this question:
[Added a custom framework, now Swift can't unarchive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569468/added-a-custom-framework-now-swift-cant-unarchive-data), which the user [answered himself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28592010/9636082):

> Moving `DemoNote` from the app to a framework did change the module name, which meant that `NSKeyedUnarchiver` couldn't find instances of the archived class due to a name mismatch.

His solution of prefixing the old project's name to the `className` string (e.g. if the project was called `"CompanyDirectory"` then using `"CompanyDirectory.Employee"` as opposed to just `"Employee"`) was what I needed to be able to unarchive my data from my model which had been moved into a newly-created linked Framework.

Comment: You're right, archive/unarchive inside the same "context" (like inside the same app) works well without doing nothing. I had the problem archiving an object into the general pasteboard from App1 and unarchiving it getting the data from the pasteboard in App2. For this usecase I had to set the class as @teriiehina said.