# Casting fails from unarchived data from NSKeyedUnarchiver, from Any? type to OIDAuthState

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to unarchive a saved object from NSKeyedUnarchiver. The unarchived data is ok, but I'm not able to cast it from Any? type to it's actual type (OIDAuthState).

```
    public func loadState() {
        if let archivedAuthState = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: stateKeychainIdentifier) as? Data {
            if let authState = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archivedAuthState) {
                setAuthState(authState as! OIDAuthState)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

I've also tried

```
if let authState: OIDAuthState = ....

if let authState = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archivedAuthState) as? OIDAuthstate { ...
```

which all fail. OIDAuthState is an Objective-C class bridged to Swift, and it inherits from NSObject and NSSecureCoding.

Answer (score 4):

The fix for this is :

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(OIDAuthState.self, forClassName: "OIDAuthState")
```

[StackOverflow answer reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28592010/1989101)